# 100% wide footer while centering content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've just started coding my first bootstrap website and after looking around still didn't manage to find a solution. It is my first time posting on stackoverflow so hopefully this questions makes sense for other people too.

I'm looking to make my footer 100% wide while centering the content with CSS.

```
<footer class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-sm-3">
            <p>1</p>
            <p>2</p>
            <p>3</p>
        </nav>
        <nav class="col-sm-3">
            <h3>Plan du Site </h3>
                <table style="">
                </table>
        </nav>
        <nav class="col-sm-3">
            <h4>some H4</h4>
        </nav>

        <nav class="col-sm-3">
            <h3>some h3</h3>
        </nav>
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS I have so far:

```
footer{
background-color: #3D383D;
padding: 15px 100px 15px 100px;
min-width: 100%;}

body > footer > div {
        align-content: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean centering the text within the `col-sm-3` divs or do you need all the text to be centered?

Comment: If you want 100% width you should be using `container-fluid` rather than `container` - but I don't understand what you mean by _"while centering the content "_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bootstrap class `text-center` for centering content inside a div, and change `container` class on footer to `container-fluid`. Furthermore remove these lines from you css because they are not necessary:

```
body > footer > div {
    align-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Mario, thank you for the very fast answer it is highly appreciated !!!!! Good day

Comment: No problem @SydneyCôcô, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

As the class `.container` has a set width, you cannot make it 100% of the viewport unless forcing it to. Use the class `.container-fluid`

http://getbootstrap.com/css/